# NOT XOR as negation of XNOR

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image]

How to explain it? I understand everything until the last thing. I didn't find anything in Boolean algebra to this specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it by using truth tables -

[image]

However for 3 variables, this does not happen. Such a relationship exists only when the number of variables is a multiple of 2.